# intersection and union of two nodes in neo4j 1.8

Tags: neo4j

i have sample database in neo4j

category:1 name cinema  ... more fields ..

category:2 name music   ... more fields ...

category:3 name sports  ... more fields ...

user:1 name Jack   ... more fields ...

user:2 name John   ... more fields ...

user:3 name Julia  ... more fields ...

user:1 likes  categories 1 3

user:2 likes  categories 2

user:3 likes  categories 1 2 3

please i need a query in neo4j  1.8
to find the intersection and union of categories of user 1 and 3 ?

Answer (score 1):

Neo4j 1.8 is an ancient version, released ~4 years ago. So consider an upgrade to a recent version since it has improved a lot since then. For details see http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/deployment-upgrading.html.

To get an serious answer to your question provide more context, e.g. provide a sample graph using http://console.neo4j.org.